# get the count and the price of category column then group by category

Tags: mysql

I have a table

equipment : (id,quantity,cost_per_unit,category)

suppose the table containing

```
   id | quantity   |cost_per_unit| category
   ---+------------+-------------+----------
   1  |   10       |     10      | dumples
   2  |   7        |     15      | dumples
   3  |   5        |     5       | fitness
```

I'm trying to get the category of equipment and the count of this category and the price of all pieces of this category
the output would be like :

```
 category | count | price
 ---------+-------+------------------------
 dumples  | 17    | 205 // ( 10*10 + 7*15 )
 fitness  | 5     | 25
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` and `group by`

```
select category,
sum(quantity) `count`,
sum(quantity * cost_per_unit) price
from table1
group by category
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2940/2)