# Get count of categories with the categories as column for two data frames having different categories

Tags: r, categories, transpose

I have two data frames as below with some categories different. For example, DF1 has A, B categories which DF2 doesn't have. I coded as below to get individual data frames y_t2, y_t3.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Firm1 = c("A", "B", "C", "L", "M", "L"))
DF2 <- data.frame(Firm2 = c("L", "M", "N", "P")) 

library(dplyr)
y <- DF1 %>% group_by(Firm1) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

y_t <- data.frame(t(y[,2:ncol(y)]))

colnames(y_t) <- data.frame(t(y[,1])) 

y_t2 <- y_t
y_t2$dataframe <- c("Firm1")


y <- DF2 %>% group_by(Firm2) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

y_t <- data.frame(t(y[,2:ncol(y)]))

colnames(y_t) <- data.frame(t(y[,1])) 

y_t3 <- y_t
y_t3$dataframe <- c("Firm2")
```

I need to convert it into dummy variables for the categories of Group as below.

[image: Final Output]

I checked links such as [get the count and the price of category column then group by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006896/get-the-count-and-the-price-of-category-column-then-group-by-category) but unable to progress using rbind.

Kindly advise how to code the logic to fetch the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t(table(do.call(rbind, lapply(list(DF1, DF2), stack))))

       values
ind     A B C L M N P
  Firm1 1 1 1 2 1 0 0
  Firm2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @onyambu. I also got the same result with rbind.fill and then replacing all NAs with 0. But your approach is very concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a little longer way, not as great as @onyambu's suggestion.

```
y_t4 <- rbind.fill(y_t2, y_t3)

y_t4[is.na(y_t4)] <- 0
```